# Cannot find module 'babel-eslint' (both standard and babel-eslint already installed locally)

Tags: standardjs

**What version of standard?**

12.0.1

**What operating system, Node.js, and npm version?**

Windows 10,
Node v10.15.1,
NPM v.6.8.0

**What did you expect to happen?**

- I install both standard and babel-eslint on devDependencies
  (locally).
- I run `standard --parser babel-eslint`
- I get the standard use babel-eslint parser to recognize babel code style and not stating
  it as style error

**What actually happened?**

- I install both standard and babel-eslint on devDependencies (locally).
- I run standard --parser babel-eslint
- I get error: Cannot find module 'babel-eslint'

I read from previous issues [85](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/85) [1167](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1167), it should be fixed when they are installed on the same level. But it does not happen on mine.

I have tried to put config below on package.json:

```
"standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
```

But it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Already solved here on the github issues https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1257

Answer (score 9):

Hi this is an old question but for who passes here in the future, those answers didn't work for me, but this one did:

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

Comment: babel-eslint is deprecated now: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$yarn add standard babel-eslint
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing:

```
npm install -g babel-eslint
```

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why this should be installed globally...